# Symfony2 extending entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I'm new in Symfony2. I need to extend entity, also I need add custom methods to repository class.

What is best way to do this?

I need have possibility to access from this class entity class methods for example getCompanyId();

```
namespace Catalog\WebBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


class ComCompany
{

    private $cmpId;

    public function getcmpId() {
        return $this->cmpId
    }
}

class ComCompanyService extends ComCompany
{
    public function getcmpIdChanget() {
      return ($this->cmpId) * 2
    }
}
```

Also I need have possibility to access repository class methods

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$products = $em->getRepository('WebBundle:ComCompanyService')
    ->getcmpId();
```

Maybe it's poor example, but I thing you understand what I want. What I need to use for this ? Services or EntityRepository ? or something else ?

Comment: mate, you really need to read documentation - everything is there: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski `Custom Repository Classes` is not what I need.